# How to retrieve association based on join table scope in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, associations

I have three models, User, Registrant, Program.

Registrant is a join table between User and Program and contains `user_id`, `program_id` and `status`, which is an enum.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :registrants, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :programs, through: :registrants
end
```

```
class Registrant < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :program

    enum status: {
        enrolled: 1,
        unenrolled: 2,
        instructor: 3,
        passed: 4,
        failed: 5
    }

    scope :active, -> { where(status: [:enrolled, :instructor]) }
end
```

```
class Program < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :registrants, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :registrants
end
```

I would like to be able to retrieve only records from the join table that have an enum status of :enrolled or :instructor, so that I can do something like:

`program.registrants.active.users`

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Long chains like `program.registrants.active.users` should be avoided due to the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) so that not a good goal.

You can add conditions to joined table in `.where` by passing a hash:

```
program.users.where(
  registrants: { status: [:enrolled, :instructor] }
)
```

Note that the key should be the table name (or its alias in the query) and not the name of the association.

You can also pass a scope:

```
program.users.where(Registrant.active)
```

And you can clean this up additionally be creating a "scoped" association:

```
class Program < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :registrants, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :registrants
    has_many :active_users, 
             through: :registrants,
             source: :user,
             -> { where(Registrant.active) }

end
```

Which will let you call:

```
program.active_users # Demeter is happy.
```

Comment: When I try to add the scope on the association, it throws an error:
`** ArgumentError Exception: Unsupported argument type: #<Registrant::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fbdcb0f4c28> (Registrant::ActiveRecord_Relation)`

Comment: Ah, it seems I needed `-> { where(registrants: Registrant.active) }`. Everything looks like it's working now. Thank you!